# Scrapy returning weirdly encoded string

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using scrapy and getting a weird response. The url looks like this (notice the utf-8 encoded check mark: https://www.example.com?sort=relevancy&utf8=%E2%9C%9

I'm getting a 200 response but the string is bytes looking like this:

```
b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\xec\xbd\xedv\xdb\xb6\xb20\xfc?W\x81r\x9f\'\xb6OE\x8a\....
```

What is this? How do I handle this? Can I have scrapy automatically decode stuff that looks like this?

Comment: Decode the response using `.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: Where should I put this code so Scrapy always knows to handle it? Also, when I try, I get: {UnicodeDecodeError}'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Comment: what is read url for this data?  It may use different encoding then UTF-8. Or it can be bytes data like image and you can't decode it.

Comment: Well what url are you retrieving? Is it actually utf8? Check the encoding header of the response

Comment: there can be other situation - you can get result compressed with gzip or br. You would have to uncompress it. When I check url in browser I see header `content-encoding: br`. OR you would have to set header: "Accept-Encoding: deflate" in request and then server will not use `gzip` or `bz`

Answer (score 2):

The answer is on the @drec4s and @furas comments.

You can try first to decode the response

```
response.body.decode('utf-8')
```

Or also

```
response.body_as_unicode()
```

If you get decoding errors or an unreadable string you might try different encodings, but most likely the response's body is compressed. Check in the response headers for something like

```
content-encoding: br
```

Or it could also be 'gzip'

In that case, you need to ask the server to return an uncompressed response by setting in the request headers:

```
accept-encoding: deflate
```